# jquery .on() triggering event twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some dynamically generated form fields. I would like to update an input field based off the value of the one just changed.  After fiddling with the code below, the event seems to fire twice (because the alert fires twice).  The first triggering changes the text field like I desire, however on the second changes it to zero.  Why is the below code firing twice?  How can I prevent this?

Coffeescript

```
$(document).on 'change','#qty', ->
  $('#amount').val($(this).val())
  alert($(this).val())
```

Javascript equivalent to above

```
$(document).on('change', '#qty', function() {
  $('#amount').val($(this).val());
  return alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Most likely you are binding the event twice.

Comment: Are you running this code once you dynamically add the element?

Comment: Yes.  I have a link which adds the form fields.  after generating the fields I attempt to change the value.

Comment: you don't need the event delegation version of .on.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with `on()` function. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/f35HX/).

The code:

```
$('body').append($('<input>').attr('id', 'dynamic'));
$(document).on('keyup', '#dynamic', function(e) {
    console.log(e, e.target);
    /*
    Since all functions in JavaScript has a return value, 
    and if you don't specify them they would default to undefined, 
    thus you might return something explicitly here. 
    But it has no effect upon the execution of the on() function.
    */
});
```

I guess you bind the even handler twice. That's the most likely case. To test that, I recommend that you first check the attached handlers to the `#dynamic` element using `$('#dynamic').data('events')`. If it's undefined, then you haven't bound any handler yet, but if it returns an object, then you've bound some event to it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running the code every time you add the element, simply bind directly to it.

```
$("#qty").on("change",...
```

Comment: For some reason that doesn't seem to fire any event

Comment: @ctilley79 Can you give us a bit more context? Where is this code located in relation to you adding the elements?